# Add full background image using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm building small script, a fullscreen slideshow with description, but i'm having some issues adding the images, it seems that the images are not being recognized.

http://jsfiddle.net/w7c3gzvd/

I would like to add this code too

```
"no-repeat center center fixed;"
```

to fix the background.

What am i doing wrong?

```
var i = 1;

function slideshow() {
    setTimeout(function() {

        if (i == 2) {
            $("body").css("http://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/046/003/original/fuchsia-background-with-light-beams-no-bar.jpg)");
            $("#description").text("teste1");
        }
        if (i == 3) {
            $("body").css("http://i1.wp.com/static.web-backgrounds.net/uploads/2012/08/City_Landscape_Background.jpg)");
            $("#description").text("teste2");
        }
        if (i == 4) {
            $("body").css("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-AISNX1W0-ww/UXZ80eprU8I/AAAAAAAAAoI/e4-7I79LmKI/s1600/background+wallpaper+6742.jpg)");
            $("#description").text("teste3");
            i = 1;
        }

        i++;
        if (i < 5) {
            slideshow();
        }

    }, 1000)
}

slideshow();
```

Thanks

Comment: You're implementing the css method incorrectly, [.css( propertyName, value )] [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7c3gzvd/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not implementing jquery's .css() correctly.  You have to pass it the property name and value as parameters http://api.jquery.com/css/

```
.css( propertyName, value )
```

So to set a background image (and the additional parameters you required) you could use:

```
$(body).css('background','url("http://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/046/003/original/fuchsia-background-with-light-beams-no-bar.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just setting the css to be the image url. You'll need to set the css background image url to be the url of the image..

```
$("body").css("background-image", "url('your photo url here')")
```